# Solving eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Given the equation:

$$f'' + af = 0, \quad   0 < x < L$$

Solve for an equation with roots that are eigenvalues. Find these eigenvalues an and verify through calculation that these are real. Find the corresponding eigenfunctions $f_n$.

I want an equation with roots that are eigenvalues. Is this $1+a=0$? Then is the only eigenvalue $-1$? This seems wrong.

Comment: What's $f',f, L$?

Comment: $$f'', f $$ are some function and it second derivative. L is some constant.

Comment: Function from where to where, $\mathbb{R}$ to itself?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: Your problem is incomplete: your eigenvalues & eigenfunctions are **not even defined** until you have imposed boundary conditions. Otherwise, clearly, for *any* $a$ you get a $2-$D space of solutions. Revise?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have phrased your question makes it quite unclear what you are asking. Nonetheless, let's see if I can guess what you're trying to say.

You want to ask yourself: "What functions do I know of which are related to their second derivatives?" There are three possible answers (assuming $a \neq 0$)

1. $\sin(x), \cos(x)$,
2. $\sinh(x), \cosh(x)$,
3. $e^x$

Now luckily, $e^x$ actually captures the information provided by the previous two answers, so we will ignore them for the moment and work only with $e^x$. As an ansatz, assume then that $f(x)=e^{mx}$ for some to-be-determined value of $m$. The fact that $f'' + af = 0$ means we can substitute to find
$$ m^2 e^{mx} + a e^{mx} = 0.$$
Since $e^{mx}$ is never zero, we may quotient by it to get the equation $m^2 + a = 0$.

Now to proceed depends on our choice of $a$. If $a<0$ then $m = \pm\sqrt{-a}$ are two real numbers, implying that $f_+(x) = e^{\sqrt ax}$ and $f_-(x) = e^{-\sqrt ax}$ are two solution. By the principle of linear superposition, the total possible solution is $A e^{\sqrt ax} + B e^{-\sqrt a x}$ and this actually corresponds to an equivalent solution in terms of $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$.

If $a>0$, then $m = \pm i \sqrt {a}$ and again our general solution is $Ae^{i\sqrt a x}+ B e^{-i\sqrt a x}$ for constants $A,B$. This corresponds to the $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ solution. In both of the above cases, to determine $A,B$ you need conditions on your domain $0<x<L$.

As an eigenfunction problem, consider the differential operator $D = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. Then your equation $f'' + af = 0$ amounts to saying that $-a$ is the eigenvalue of $D$ with eigenfunction $f$, since $Df = -a f$. Indeed, applying $D$ to every case above gives $-a$ as an eigenvalue, and $f$ as an eigenfunction.

Comment: Your last paragraph is misleading, cf. my comment to the question.

Comment: The eigenvalue is certainly well-defined regardless of boundary conditions. The argument for the eigenfunction likely depends on the class of functions you would like to examine; we could specify boundary value problems, but why not define an eigenfunction as any element in the $\mathbb R$-submodule of $C^2(\mathbb R)$ spanned by "fundamental solutions"? How about eigenfunctions of elliptic differential operators over the real tangent bundle? I tried to account for the possibility that OP omitted BC's, but I think we're okay without them.

Comment: No, they're not (well-defined) - & much less certainly so - unless jakenfinn wants to redefine the term. The (normative) definition I use is ${\cal L}f = \lambda f$ for some $f\ne0$ - i.e., an eigenvalue is an element of the point spectrum of the operator ${\cal L}$. I suggest looking at the problem $f''+af=0$ on $[0,L]$ - that is, the one given above - with Dirichlet ($f(0)=f(L)=0$) & Neumann ($f'(0)=f'(L)=0$) boundary conditions. You'll find that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue in the latter case (eigenfunction: any constant function) but not in the former (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I think that you misunderstand what I was saying. Certainly, you may define an eigenfunction with respect to an operator with associated boundary conditions, but in that case the boundary conditions are part of the definition of the operator (or define your solution space if you prefer some sort of isoparametric viewpoint, which is what you are doing if you are looking at the point spectrum of the operator). But why limit ourselves to (O/P)DE theory or functional analytical POV's?

Comment: I understand what *I* am saying (but thank you for recapping), yet I'm indeed confused as to what *you* are saying, as well as what is being asked. No BCs means that *every* number is an eigenvalue; hence, I tend to read the restriction '*with roots that are eigenvalues*' in the original problem as useless. Both the original problem & your answer stand down-voted until this is resolved; the rest is semantics from my POV. Sorry about that.

Comment: That is fine, such is the manner of the forum! I believe my argument stands sound, but it may well just be pedantics. If only the OP would amend the statement so that I could amend mine. :)

Comment: Thanks for being a sport :). Such is academic life, indeed...